# Table Value Function, Select Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table value function which splits up strings by a common delimiter and outputs them into a table with the following structure :

```
@ValueLookup TABLE 
(
    Value nvarchar(100),
    ValueIndex int
)
```

I'm using this mostly to split combination ID values, such as `1234-5678` :

```
dbo.SplitString('1234-5678', '-')
```

Currently, I'm using two `SELECT`'s to get both values once they are split, along with converting them to integers :

```
DECLARE @FirstID INT
DECLARE @SecondID INT
SELECT 
    @FirstID = CONVERT(INT, Value)
FROM dbo.SplitString('1234-5678', '-')
WHERE ValueIndex = 1
SELECT 
    @SecondID = CONVERT(INT, Value)
FROM dbo.SplitString('1234-5678', '-')
WHERE ValueIndex = 2
```

Is there a way I could get both values and assign them in a single `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @FirstId int, @SecondId int;
select 
    @FirstID  = convert(int,min(case when ValueIndex = 1 then Value end))
  , @SecondID = convert(int,min(case when ValueIndex = 2 then Value end))
from dbo.SplitString('1234-5678', '-')

select 
    FirstId  = @FirstId
  , SecondId = @SecondId
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TRTDI68038

returns:

```
+---------+----------+
| FirstId | SecondId |
+---------+----------+
|    1234 |     5678 |
+---------+----------+
```

Demo was done using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden with the function name and output columns renamed.

---

Splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)
- [Ordinal workaround for **`string_split()**` - Solomon Rutzky](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2433171)

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize you could reference another row value in the `CASE` statement. Since I have a few minutes before I can accept, I'm curious on the use of `MIN` there? Is that just a good practice for the conversion?

Comment: @X3074861X The choice of `min()` is arbitrary. You could just as well use `max()`. You could also use `sum()` if you converted to `int` inside the aggregate function instead of outside.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option

**Example**

```
Declare @String varchar(max) = '1234-5678'
Declare @FirstID INT
Declare @SecondID INT

Select @FirstID  = xDim.value('/x[1]','int')
      ,@SecondID = xDim.value('/x[2]','int')
From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(@String,'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A
```